# Laravel 5.6:How to create db query inside a foreach loop and display the result in a view corresponding to the product id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'am a laravel newbie. I'am trying to create a point of sale system: It has a sales area where the users can search for product and click on the product they need to sell. Once clicked the product is added to the cart together with its serials.I have three tables involved:

**1ST TABLE**
Items_master: this table stores the product names, buying and selling price

**2ND TABLE**
Stock_quantities: this table stores the product quantities according to the shop by product_id and shop_id.

**3RD TABLE**
Stock_serials: this table stores the serials of all products by product_id and shop_id.

**Here is the code**

**MAIN QUERY**
[Products query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m68x.png)

**SERIALS QUERY**
[Serials query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj24o.png)

**VIEW**
[PRODUCTS VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mICNy.png)

The problem is, if more than one product is selected,it displays the serials of only one product.I would like  each product selected to be accompanied by its serials in a dropdown.

Comment: Please share you code inline, not in images. This helps to reproduce your error

Comment: Please do post the code next time, typing it all out is annoying and error-prone.

Comment: So, to check. The user selects more than one product. They should then be show, for each product, a dropdown with the associated serials?

Comment: Also, are you using Models / Eloquent? There's a lot of manual querying there.

Comment: @Kurucu Yes, that is correct:The user selects more than one product. They should then be show, for each product, a dropdown with the associated serials.Yes,I'am using laravel raw query builder.